# Looking for CSS-File for Views

Tags: views, theming

when using Views Format:Unformatted List and Show:Fields I get lots of Style Classes referenced by default (e.g. "views-row-odd") within the resulting html-code.

1) Until now I couldn't find a corresponding css-file that defines formats for all the classes in the generated code. Am I missing something ?

2) As test, I tried to include a self-written css-file to the folder "modules\contrib\views\css" and referenced it in the views.info file (stylesheets[all][]=...). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, since the generated html code is missing <<@import url("hxx://adr/drupal/modules/contrib/views/css/my_style.css..:>>. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your support,

Martin
PS: Using Bartik as theme ...

Comment: why you don't using Firebug browser plugin to view structure and css, and than override css in global.css file?